# How to display actual data from DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I´m doing SQL to display actual subject which is teaching currently by this and this teacher. It should displays only name of subject(f.e. it displays 'languages'   at 8am at Teacher´s profile). In database I have table - timetable and there are data of start_time and end_time which are saved in DATETIME. I have problem how to interconnect SQL and PHP and then display. 
I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT lessons.schoolday, lessons.start_time, lessons.end_time, lectors.lectorsurname, studentgroups.class_id, classes.grade, subjects.subjectname 
  FROM lessons INNER JOIN lectors ON lessons.lector_id=lectors.lector_id 
     INNER JOIN studentgroups ON lessons.studentgroup_id=studentgroups.studentgroup_id 
     INNER JOIN classes ON studentgroups.class_id=classes.class_id 
     INNER JOIN subjects ON lessons.subject_id=subjects.subject_id 
    WHERE lessons.start_time <= substring(('".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'),11,6)
    AND lessons.end_time >= substring(('".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'),11,6) 
    AND lectors.lector_id=:id");
```

When I change date instead of interval(f.e. start_time->0000-00-00 08:00:00, end_time->0000-00-00 08:45:00), it is working. But in this way, it prints only Array(). HTML is displaying with Latte template and there is condition, if empty array, it displays message=Teacher is not teaching currently, but this is also not working.

.......

php code:

```
     $stmt3 = $db->prepare(" SELECT l.schoolday, l.start_time, l.end_time, t.lectorsurname, sg.class_id, c.grade, s.subjectname 
                                FROM lessons l 
                                INNER JOIN lectors       t  ON l.lector_id=t.lector_id 
                                INNER JOIN studentgroups sg ON l.studentgroup_id=sg.studentgroup_id 
                                INNER JOIN classes       c  ON sg.class_id=c.class_id 
                                INNER JOIN subjects      s  ON l.subject_id=s.subject_id 
                                WHERE l.start_time <= CURTIME() AND l.end_time >= CURTIME() AND t.lector_id=:id
                                ORDER By c.grade, l.schoolday, l.start_time"); 
        $stmt3->bindValue(":id", intval($_GET["id"]));
        $stmt3->execute();
       $data=$stmt3->fetchAll();
       print_r($data);

$tplVars["lesson"] = $stmt3->fetchAll();
```

and latte template

```
    <table>
    . 
    .
    .
    <tr>
        <th> Aktuálne vyučuje: </th>
    </tr>
    {foreach $lesson as $aktual}
     {if !empty($aktual['grade'])}  
    <tr>
      <td>{$aktual['grade']} </td>
    </tr>
     {/if}
     {if ($aktual['grade']) == NULL}
    <tr> <td> <span> Učiteľ momentálne nevyučuje </span></td></tr>
     {/if}
    {/foreach}
</table>
```

Comment: You have to add your php code to the question for us to help with that.

Comment: Use PHP mysqli query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

Search for some examples. with some aliases its better readable. Is a NOW() not enough? see [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for more MySql date and time functions

```
SELECT l.schoolday, l.start_time, l.end_time, t.lectorsurname, sg.class_id, c.grade, s.subjectname 
FROM lessons l 
INNER JOIN lectors       t  ON l.lector_id=t.lector_id 
INNER JOIN studentgroups sg ON l.studentgroup_id=sg.studentgroup_id 
INNER JOIN classes       c  ON sg.class_id=c.class_id 
INNER JOIN subjects      s  ON l.subject_id=s.subject_id 
WHERE l.start_time <= NOW() AND l.end_time >= NOW() AND t.lector_id=:id
```

Comment: Actually, it seems OP only needs the time part of datetime, so might need `CURTIME()`.

Comment: Im trying now, curtime and it still displays Array()

Comment: looking at this row: print_r($data); it seems that there are no records found in your database that meet the conditions you wrote in your query.

Comment: SELECT l.schoolday, l.start_time, l.end_time, t.lectorsurname, sg.class_id, c.grade, s.subjectname FROM lessons l INNER JOIN lectors t ON l.lector_id=t.lector_id INNER JOIN studentgroups sg ON l.studentgroup_id=sg.studentgroup_id INNER JOIN classes c ON sg.class_id=c.class_id INNER JOIN subjects s ON l.subject_id=s.subject_id WHERE l.start_time <= CURTIME() AND l.end_time >= CURTIME()   ... I dont understand why it displays data without the condition, and when I add condition it doesnt displays... Can be problem in datetime? The start_time and end_time is saved like 0000-00-00 08:00:00 f.e.